# If a matrix is an outer product of two vectors; can I determine the vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-mathematics, svd, outer-product

I am working with floating point numbers. There is a 3x3 matrix that has determinant 1e-14.

I have reason to believe this matrix is an outer product of two vectors. If the assumption is correct, how would I find out which vectors it is?

Comment: What dimension?

Comment: The matrix is 3x3

Comment: Certainly not if one of the two vectors is zero. Also, if $v\otimes w$ denotes the outer product, then
$$v\otimes w=(\lambda v)\otimes(\lambda^{-1} w),$$
for any scalar $\lambda$. So at best, you can retrieve them up to scaling.

Comment: @Servaes... Huh?  Of *course* if one of the vectors is zero.  (Jeez.). Now you just have an infinite number of other pairs of vectors to test.  And NO... the dot denotes *dot* product (not outer product).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I do not understand any part of your comment. Have you read the question?

Comment: Yes, I read the question.  It is saying she believes that there exist two (unknown) vectors whose outer product yields the matrix in question.  Given the extra information about the determinant, find the values of the two vectors.  Stating that neither of the vectors can be zero provides minuscule information.  Imagine a problem where someone says "I have a composite number that I think has exactly two factors... how do I find them?" and you responds, "well, neither of them can be *0*."  OK, sure.  Correct.  But so what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v\otimes w$ denote the outer product of two vectors $v$ and $w$. If $v=0$ then $v\otimes w=0$ for any $w$, and so it is not possible to retrieve $w$.

If $v\neq0$ and $w\neq0$, then still for any nonzero scalar $\lambda$ you have
$$(\lambda v)\otimes(\lambda^{-1} w)=v\otimes w.$$
So it is again not possible to retrieve $v$ and $w$. You can retrieve them up to scaling; if the $(i,j)$-th entry of $v\otimes w$ is nonzero, say $\lambda$, then you can take $w$ to be the the $i$-th row and $v$ to be the $j$-th column divided by $\lambda$.

Of course, if you only want to know whether the matrix is an outer product of two vectors, it suffices to check that its rank is at most $1$.